# how a can extract individual pieces of data from this record:i think whit split

Tags: java

how a can  extract individual pieces of data from this record:

```
String text = 'John.Davidson/05051988/Belgrade Michael.Barton/01011968/Krakov Ivan.Perkinson/23051986/Moscow'
```

- firstname,
- Name,
- birthday,
- birthplace.

That data should be used to complete the fields of an object of type Person

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please format your example properly and explain what you mean by *invalid*. Also include your attempts to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regular Expression capturing groups](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) to parse your string.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to split the text on the whitespace - each part of this split is a different person.

```
String[] persons = text.split("\\s+");
String person1 = persons[0];
String person2 = persons[1];
```

Then you should split each "person" on '/'

```
String[] info = person1.split("/");
String name = info[0];
String birthday = info[1];
String birthplace = info[2];
```

then you split name into "." as previously in order to extract the firstname.
You should do the splits in a for loop for each person.